# Randomly delete 30% of cells data in an MS excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet with 200 rows and 150 columns (i.e. 30000 cells). I would like to delete 30% of total data randomly (i.e. from random row and random columns). It should also be fine if I can delete 30% of data randomly from one column at a time.

Please suggest a macro/formula/Java code (using POI) that can help me to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried anything yet???

Comment: And what version of excel do you use?

Comment: It's very hard to suggest a macro to do what you are wanting to do because I doubt if anyone has ever had this requirement before and therefore such a macro won't exist yet - your code will probably be the first ever written to achieve the task.  What problems are you having writing the code?

Comment: Wrote the code in python to get around this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select the range you want to work with and run this macro, or, if you have a fixed range, change `Set rng = Selection` to `Set rng = Range("A1:ET200")` or whatever your range is.

```
Sub DelThirty()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, x As Long, y As Long

Set rng = Selection

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To Int(rng.Cells.Count * 0.3)
retry:
    x = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, rng.Rows.Count)
    y = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, rng.Columns.Count)
    If rng.Cells(x, y) <> "" Then
        rng.Cells(x, y).ClearContents
    Else
        GoTo retry
    End If
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ErrHandler:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put =Rand() in last column and copy it down, sort it by large to small and then delete 60 rows

Comment: Hi Xire... It will delete random rows. But i need to delete cells randomly so that each row has some empty cells

Comment: Wrote the code in python to get around this problem. Thanks!